# SQL CTE to Sybase IQ to identify 30 consecutive days

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I need to identify the member/providers (created a key called: PRV_MBR_KEY) who have 30 consecutive dates of service with no breaks.  I've tested and validated on sample data successfully in SQL SVR.  I need to re-code this to work in Sybase IQ platform.

Sample Data:

```
PRV_MBR_KEY             FDOS_LN
330800913-00369544518   10/10/2016
330800913-00369544518   10/11/2016
330800913-00369544518   10/12/2016
330800913-00369544518   10/13/2016
330800913-00369544518   10/14/2016
330800913-00369544518   10/15/2016
330800913-00369544518   10/16/2016
330800913-00369544518   10/17/2016
330800913-00369544518   10/18/2016
330800913-00369544518   10/19/2016
```

Here's the SQL code that works:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  PRV_MBR_KEY,
[FDOS_LN],
RangeId = DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [FDOS_LN])
- ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRV_MBR_KEY ORDER BY [FDOS_LN])
FROM TEST_table)
SELECT PRV_MBR_KEY,
StartDate=MIN([FDOS_LN]),
EndDate=MAX([FDOS_LN]),
DAYCOUNT=DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN([FDOS_LN]),MAX([FDOS_LN]))+1
FROM CTE
GROUP BY PRV_MBR_KEY,RangeID
HAVING DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN([FDOS_LN]),MAX([FDOS_LN]))+1>=30
ORDER BY PRV_MBR_KEY,MIN([FDOS_LN])
```

Expected Results:

```
PRV_MBR_KEY             StartDate   EndDate     DAYCOUNT
330800913-00369544518   2016-10-10  2016-11-13  35
330800913-00565274557   2017-01-26  2017-02-24  30


The error I get when running code in Sybase IQ:
[Sybase][ODBC Driver][Sybase IQ]Data exception - argument must be DATE or 
DATETIME  --(dflib/dfe_datepart.cxx 1450)
```

Comment: I'm guessing the error is generated by this function call: `DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [FDOS_LN])` ... 2nd argument (0) needs to be a date or datetime; you should be able to confirm this is generating the error with a simple test like ... `select top 3 DATEDIFF(DAY,0,[FDOS_LN]) from TEST_table`

Comment: Yes, I tried your test and received the same error.  I'm trying to create similar logic in Sybase IQ and don't know how...

Comment: Soooo, what date are you expecting '0' to be treated/evaluated as? 1/1/1900? 1/1/1970? something else?  you must be expecting '0' to be treated as a specific date, right(?) ... so replace '0' with that specific date ... ???